# How to handle tornado user logged out state properly with coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

Simple handler:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    current_user = yield self.get_current_user()
    if not current_user:
        self.redirect('/')

    id = current_user['id']
    ...
```

---

Function for getting current user:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get_current_user(self):
    cookie = self.get_secure_cookie('user')
    if not cookie:
        return
```

I have a simple handler. It checks if the user is logged in and redirects if current_user is None. The problem arises when the user is not logged in: the line `id = current_user['id']` is still evaluated because get_current_user() is a coroutine and it will throw an exception like `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

How would you properly handle this if I want to keep `get_current_user()` as a coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use coroutine decorator in get_current_user() and call it with yield since it's a very fast function.

Switching context with coroutine in this case likely make more work than get_current_user().